# Remove "Duplicate" from Actions dropdown for Employees

Tags: drop-down-menu, odoo, odoo-10

I am new to Odoo. How can I remove the "Duplicate" option from actions dropdown in the Employees app. I am using odoo 10.0.[The image shows the option I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWypg.png)

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: I tried to modify a lot of views and see which view has the actions dropdown and had no luck. @LeonardoAlvesMachado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide by using this module,

Try with this module: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_eradicate_duplicate/

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/9.0/web_duplicate_visibility/

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

just add `copy="false"` in your form or tree view

```
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml" >
                <form string="Sales Order" class="o_sale_order" copy="false">
                </form>
            </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use duplicate = false in parent form:

```
<record id="an_id" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">a.name.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">a.model</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="parent_addon.parent_view_id"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form position="attributes">
                <attribute name="duplicate">0</attribute>
            </form>
        </field>
</record>
```

This was tested successfully in Odoo 9